# Proving that $0$ is an eigenvalue of this transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm currently self-studying linear algebra and am interested in proving the following:

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, where $ \operatorname{rank}(T)<n$, prove that $0$ is an eigenvalue of the transformation.

What I'd like to do is use the inveritable matrix theorem, where since $ \operatorname{rank}(T)$ doesn't equal $n$, I can use every part of theorem negated: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html

One such part is: "18. 0 fails to be an eigenvalue of A."

Negated: $0$ is an eigenvalue of A, in this case, T.

Thus proving $0$ is an eigenvalue of T.

What do you think of this proof? If I had the wrong idea, could you go over one way to prove it?

Comment: This is not really a proof, but rather just an application of the theorem of invertible matrices. Are you actually trying to prove this implication without use of the invertible matrix theorem (or at least this part of the theorem)?

Comment: The most recent chapters discussed applications of the theorem so I assumed it was permitted. In the case where it isnt really a proof, is it at least a correct application of the theorem?

Comment: @HistorySweets An application of a theorem is definitely a proof.

Comment: So, is the proof okay? Sorry, proofs are still pretty new to me. At this point, i'm just wrapping my head around theorems and such.

Comment: This application is certainly correct: if a matrix is not invertible it has zero as an eigenvalue (in this case the matrix associated to $T$). But if the question asks for a **proof** of this implication, then I don't think what you have really does this; a proof more relies on use of the definitions, and one cannot assume this result from the invertible matrix theorem is true a priori.

Comment: @HistorySweets Yes, it is correct. The only issue is that since all the substance is contained in the proof of the theorem, then neither the reader nor you get to see really why it is true. But as you can see, even an experienced teacher, see below, is using an argument that hides most of the work inside another theorem. So, why wouldn't you. On the other hand, do try to see a proof as expanded out as possible.

Comment: @Dave, the question in my texts says, "Let T...Prove that $0$ is an eigenvalue of T". Is that the same as asking for a proof of this implication?

Comment: Let $e_1,...,e_n$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $T(e_1),...,T(e_n)$ are $n$ vectors, that generate $Range(T)$, which they say it is of dimension $<n$. Therefore, $T(e_1),...,T(e_n)$ must be linearly dependent, i.e. there are $a_1,...,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$, not all zero, such that $0=a_1T(e_1)+...+a_nT(e_n)=T(a_1e_1+...+a_ne_n)$. Therefore, $a_1e_1+...+a_ne_n$ is a non-zero vector that gets sent to $0$ by $T$.

Comment: I suppose that question is not the same as asking for a proof of the result from the IMT. To be completely sure, maybe you should ask your instructor if you're allowed to use the IMT.

Answer (score 1):

An eigenvector for the value $0$ is just a non-trivial member of the null space or kernel of $T$: a vector $x \neq 0$ such that $Tx=0$.

And the [nullity rank theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) says that $\dim(\operatorname{ker}(T)) + \operatorname{rank}(T) = n (= \dim(\mathbb{R}^n))$, so if the rank is $< n$ we
know $\dim(\operatorname{ker}(T)) > 0$ and so take any non-zero vector in it.

Answer (score 1):

We have  the Kernel of T is non empty, since the Rank of T is less than the dimension $n$.

That is $Tv=0$ for some $v\ne 0$

$Tv=0=0v$ implies that $0$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $v$